# Can't remove border of input element

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, materialize

I am using Chrome. I am using Materialize CSS (in an Angular app). I can't remove the blue border that surrounds my number input on focus. I have tried many variations of the below, as well as some I have certainly left out in my repetition.

```
<div class="input-field">
  <label class="" for="customTarget">Desired value:</label>
  <input id="customTarget" type="number" class="validate" step="any" min="0">
</div>

input:focus, input {
  outline: none;
  outline-style: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: solid 2px transparent;
}
```

Please, what have I missed?

Comment: You missed supplying the required HTML so we know what you're doing there.

Comment: simply make it more specific than whatever is currently styling it.

Comment: Thank you, updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is to add !important after the attributes you want to change in your css code.

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="number" />
```

Comment: That is a hack. An act of desperation. Something of last resort till you can figure it out later. Also, the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash. The same is true with `<link>`

Comment: this is not a hack mate! you are using a library to style your code! this will be generalized on all your code so you have to override some of it!
If you want this to effect every input in your website this is the way how to do it

Comment: If you want to apply it partially there is several ways, by creating a css class or write it inline in you input.

Comment: I tried to write it inline in the input, to no avail. I guess I need to refresh my cascading hierarchy, especially with libraries. But, for `!important` will have to do. Thanks all!

Comment: it absolutely is a hack. there's always a better alternative to !important

Answer (score 2):

Do it in the angular side.

(html)

```
<input style="border: transparent" type="text" aria-label="M.I." class="form-control">
```

Answer (score -1):

It is somewhat looked down upon to use `!important`, but it's quick and dirty, gets the job done.

Your styles are getting trumped in the cascade of styles, you could try being more explicit with `input:focus` by going with `body .content input:focus` - this way you're avoiding the `!important`, and by being more explicit this style will override the built in Materialize styles.

Comment: Naturally this worked.. I feel a bit foolish that I didn't realize the CSS was being trumped, likely by something more explicit in Materialize. I guess my take away is be more explicit when using a library, or resort to `!important`. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime! I'm trying to boost my rep in order to be able to properly upvote everyone who has ever helped me, but instead, some db downvotes my helpful answer, StackOverflow community disappoints.